# Assigning a value to a pointer to a const pointer to a const char (const char * const * p)

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am new to C++ and am struggling to make the following code work:

```
struct Keywords
{
     const char* const* keys;
     int count;
}

Keywords GetKeywords()
{
     Keywords keywords;
     keywords.count = 10;
     string keys = "a b c d e";
     keywords.keys = keys???;
     return keywords;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     Keywords keywords = GetKeywords();
     cout<<keywords.count<<endl; //prints 10
     cout<<keywords.keys<<endl;  //prints a memory address like 0030F838
}
```

How can I make `keys` to point to `a b c d e`?
So far I have tried this

```
char * writable = new char[keys.size() + 1];
strcpy(writable, keys.c_str());
writable[keys.size()] = '\0';

const char* a = writable;
const char** ptr = &a;
results.keys = ptr;
```

While debugging I can see that `results.keys` shows `a b c d e`, but as soon as `GetKeywords()` is returned, `results.keys` points to unreadable memory location.

I cannot make any changes to `struct Keywords` and `GetKeywords()` method signature.

Comment: Your attempt is wrong since you store a pointer to a local variable inside the `GetKeywords` function. Once the function returns the life-time of all local variables inside the functions ends, and they go out of scope.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: And what is the reason for you wanting a pointer *to a pointer*? Do you want an "array" of strings, where the first element is the string `"a"`, the second `"b"` etc.? What is the *real* problem you have?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, I could have used an easier approach to return the values, but this one is an assignment and I just can't make this last part work. The result should be returned as Keywords GetKeywords(). No other options.

Comment: @ulughbekula : Like Miles Budnek asks, why not use a `std::vector<std::string>` here ? Are you barred from changing the `struct Keywords` in your assignment ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar Yes. I cannot make any changes to the struct and `GetKeywords()` signature.

Comment: Then *what are you supposed to do?* What is supposed to be the result of calling `GetKeywords`? What is `keys` supposed to point to?

Comment: @ulughbekula `const char* const* keys` means `keys` is an `array of char array`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm trying to print `"a b c d e"` with `cout<<keywords.keys;` in `main()`.

Comment: @TaQuangTu I want to print `const char* const* keys` afterwards. Could you, please, give me an example of usage?

Comment: As mentioned, `keys` is a pointer *to a pointer*. It will point to another pointer, which in turn might point to a string. But you can not print a string by using plain `keys`. Possibly you could use `*keys`. And is that your only assignment, to have a *single string* and *print the single string*? Or are you supposed to *tokenize* the string `"a b c d e"` into five different strings and print them in a loop?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The string `"a b c d e"` will be printed in loop after it is tokenized using a non-alpha char.

Comment: @ulughbekula: can you remove your `const` syntax at line `const char* const* keys;`?

Comment: @TaQuangTu : apparently, the OP can't make any changes to the struct.

Comment: Then you're probably supposed to split the single string `"a b c d e"` into five strings, and that's why you need a pointer to a pointer. The first pointer is supposed to be for an "array" of string, the second pointer is for each string itself. Now do you know how to allocate memory for an "array" of anything in C++? Do you know how to "tokenize" or split a string? Begin with those first.

Comment: @ulughbekula. If a `keyword.keys={ "key1" , "key2" , "key3" }`. And you want to show `key1 key2 key3` on your screen by using `cout<<keyword.keys`. Are you having a perfect `getKeyword()` function and no need to modify it? I can help you if you response my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the hints given by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), [Miles Budnek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151599/miles-budnek) and others I was able to solve the problem like explained below:

In my original question, the keys were represented by `string keys = "a b c d e";`. 
But in the assignment that I'm working on `a b c d e` was built by iterating over a `set<string>` items. So here is how it is done:

```
struct Keywords
{
    const char* const* keys;
    int count;
}

Keywords GetKeywords()
{
    Keywords keywords;
    keywords.count = 5;

    set<string> keys;
    GetKeys(keys);//returns keys = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

    char** charKeysPtr = new char *[keys.size() + 1];
    set<string>::iterator it;
    int index = 0;

    //Iterate the set and copy each key
    for (it = keys.begin(); it != keys.end(); it++)
    {
        charKeysPtr[index] = new char[it->size() + 1];
        strcpy(charKeysPtr[index], it->c_str());
        charKeysPtr[index][it->size()] = '\0';
        index++;
    }

    keywords.Keys = charKeysPtr;

    return keywords;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     Keywords keywords = GetKeywords();

     //Print keys
     for (int i = 0; i < keywords.count; ++i)
        cout << keywords.keys[i] << " ";

     //Output is "a b c d e"

     //Memory cleanup and etc.
}
```

Thank you guys!